# Can a timer be abandoned safely

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

Are Timers in .NET safe to abandon without calling Dispose() or Close()?

```
static System.Timers.Timer timer = new Timer();

void Main()
{
    timer.Elapsed += LogTimer_Elapsed(object, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs);
    timer.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(10000); // Simulate doing something on main thread
}

static void LogTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

Anyone see any problems with this solution?

```
static QueueLogger()
{
    LogQueue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<Logger, LogEntry>>(50);
    LogTimer = new Timer();
    LogTimer.Elapsed +=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(LogTimer_Elapsed);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
}

static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LogTimer.Stop();
    LogTimer.Dispose();
    LogTimer_Elapsed(sender, null);  // This is to process any remaining messages in the queue
}

static void LogTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        while (LogQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            var queuedLogger = LogQueue.Dequeue();
            try
            {
                if (e != null) queuedLogger.Value.Message += " From " + sender.ToString();
                queuedLogger.Key.Log(queuedLogger.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnLoggingError(queuedLogger.Key, "Async Logging error", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The timer isn't the problem.  The real question is whether the code you run in the Elapsed event is safe to abort when the process terminates.  Maybe, impossible to tell.  Don't do anything like update a dbase or write to a file.

Comment: @Hans: Actually writting to a file is exactlly what would be done.  Here is the idea.  I wanted to extend a logging framework to allow asyncronous logging using the timer and a queue.  But I didn't want the user of the logging network to have to bother with disposing as none of the other logger types need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galford,

Yes, you can create new event which will fire if your application is about to exit e.g. OnExit and listen to the event when you application's main thread is about to close. Once that is done you can create event logic and do your timer, business or clean up logic in OnExit event. Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: Where is the OnExit event handler that I should use?

Comment: You can attach or wire up to the AppDomain process exit event as shown below,

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(Application_OnExit);           
        // do some work
    }

    void Application_OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do timer clean up etc.
    }

Comment: Thanks, I found it.  I updated my original post with my implementation for any comments/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not dispose of it explicitly it will be cleaned up on the garbage collector's finalizer queue.  Although this is "safe" you will incur a performance penalty. It is best to dispose your timer.

Comment: Is there a way to know if an application is exiting?  My purpose is to write a library that will use the timer to periodically do something, but I don't want the user to be required to dispose and cleanup anything on the library.

Comment: What penalty would that incure?

Comment: @galford13x why don't you want the user to clean things up? That is the way the IDisposable pattern works.  Any class that needs to free a system resource should be doing so via its finalizer, so you don't get hosed if someone forgets to dispose an object.

Comment: I'd suggest that your library have an Initialize() and Shutdown() method, the former would allocate and start your timer, and the latter would stop and dispose it.  You can handle any other resource allocation and cleanup as well.  FYI - There's a good MSDN article on the 3 different .NET timer flavors here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: @holtavolt why not simply use the constructor and the dispose pattern? this is a well known usage pattern.

Comment: Also note that without an explicit stop of the timer, you may encounter errors on application shutdown where the timer fires while the application is preparing to exit (and in a bad state).

Comment: @weston execution of the finalizer puts extra load on the GC. If this is just a single timer that gets finalized on shutdown then no, it's not a huge deal.

Comment: @roken Yes - you could use a library ctor to initialize, and require the client to Dispose to perform the shutdown.  The only difference is decoupling timer activation/stopping from the resource management.

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx :

"When a timer is no longer needed, use the Dispose method to free the resources held by the timer."

So if you want your timer to run until the end of the program, then you do not need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection will cleanup up the Timer if you do not dispose of it.  If the timer is in in .exe and the process will just be exited when the timer ends you really don't have to worry about.  If your writing a library where the timer will be referenced you would want to dispose of it to free resources to make your library more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Calling Dispose() allows the cleanup of unmanaged resources used by your managed object before the garbage collector decides to cleanup the managed object, during which operation the unmanaged resources are also cleaned.

Calling Dispose() is usually about memory usage optimization, however, in some circumstances, not calling Dispose() will actually cause your software to not function properly. Eg: Because the number of ethernet ports is limited, not releasing them after usage may cause the system to run out of network ports. This is commonly known as "TCP/IP Port Exhaustion", and can occur when you do not call Dispose() on managed objects that use network resources (eg. WCF Clients).

As a general rule, it is always a smart idea to call Dispose() when you do no longer need any object which class implements IDisposable. (or use it in a using{} block).

In the example you provided, it seems like your timer variable is static, and bound to the main thread. It also seems like you are using your timer to the end of your program. So in this specific case, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: The provided code was to provide a simple example.  I see your point however.  In my case, I have a separate assembly that provides logging capability.  I wanted to extend the assembly by adding an Asynchronous logger.  Generally speaking most loggers don't require special shutdown code as that is normally contained in the logging framework.  I didn't want to add the requirement to this already nice simple framework.